# Cant get a non-transparent div in css ,html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a pop up with scrolling data . I made a div which will remain Fixed and I used property fixed . But Now It became transparent. I tried  using Opacity property but I was unable to do that . I have attached snapshot and code .[Snapshot of work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/531KB.png)

```css
p#lable-view-div { position: fixed; width :1083px; height: 126px; color: white; padding: 10px; background-color: #0085DA; }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete working snippet and not just the CSS.

Comment: @DanPhilip thank you for comment I got answer and accepted . Problem was I didnt added "z-index: 9999;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add z-index:

```
p#lable-view-div { 
  position: fixed; 
  width :1083px; 
  height: 126px; 
  color: white; 
  padding: 10px; 
  background-color: #0085DA; 
  z-index: 9999;
}
```